# Building Android 7 from sources: export_includes and import_includes related error

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, ninja

I encountered the following error when I tried to build Android 7 (QAEP from [codeaurora.org](https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/WebHome)):

```
ninja: error:
'out/target/product/msm8916_64/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/
  libqct_resampler_intermediates/export_includes', needed by
'out/target/product/msm8916_64/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/
  libaudioresampler_intermediates/import_in', 
missing and no known rule to make it
make: *** [build/core/ninja.mk:149: ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I did a quick `find` for `*qct*` and `*audioresampler*`. The first one returned only a few source files from the *vendor wlan driver*, but no library (e.g. `libqct` directory). And the second returned nothing at all.

**What does this error mean? Are there missing modules, that are referenced but not included in the `manifest`?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i face this problem too. As the [blog](https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8d030b2b7177188339370d/#) said, qualcomm does not supply the properties code caused that problem, the blog does not provide it too.